# comparison of two dataframe to return just single boolean

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pytest

I have two data frame d1 and d3. when I compare d1==d3 it returns row x column True or False. As, of now I'm converting to df to dict for assertion. Is there a simple way to return True if all were true and False if any False found. I'm using assert equality in py.test so, it will be use full.

`.any()` returns rows of boolean

With Dictionary:

```
def test_test001():
    if df1.shape==df2.shape :
        assert df1.to_dict()==df2.to_dict()
    else:
        assert 0, "Row are mis-matching"
def test_test002():
        assert df1.to_dict()==df3.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_test001 _________________________________
    def test_test001():
        if df1.shape==df2.shape :
            assert df1.to_dict()==df2.to_dict()
        else:
>           assert 0, "Row are mis-matching"
E           AssertionError: Row are mis-matching
E           assert 0
untitled0.py:19: AssertionError
===================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 6.43 seconds ======================
```

With DataFrame

```
def test_test001():
    if df1.shape==df2.shape :
        assert df1.to_dict()==df2.to_dict()
    else:
        assert 0, "Row are mis-matching"
def test_test002():
        assert df1==df3
```

Output:

```
________________________________ test_test001 _________________________________
...
________________________________ test_test002 _________________________________
    def test_test002():
>           assert df1==df3
untitled0.py:22:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
self =    CustomerID CustomerAltID CustomerName Gender
0        True          True   ...       True         True   True
14       True          True         True   True
    def __nonzero__(self):
        raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
                         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
>                        .format(self.__class__.__name__))
E       ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.
bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
..\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:714
: ValueError
========================== 2 failed in 6.54 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: Sorry are you asking for `df1.equals(df2)`?

Comment: In general comparison of  two dataframes. I added this to show usecase. I was looking some thing like `sql minus`